# RLMException: Object type does not match RLMArray type

Tags: swift, realm

I have a simple object:

```
class MyObject : Object {
    dynamic var dummyField: String!;
}
```

and another object which inherits from `MyObject`:

```
class MyOtherObject : MyObject {
    dynamic var anotherDummyField: String!;
}
```

Now I do the following. I have a Realm List of `MyObject` and I create an instance of `MyOtherObject` and try to save it inside the list:

```
class Operator {
    internal var myObjects: List<MyObject>!;

    internal var myObject: MyObject!;

    func operate() {
        self.myObject = MyOtherObject();
        self.myObject.dummyField = "dummy field";
        self.myObject.anotherDummyField = "another dummy field";

        self.myObjects = List<MyObject>();
        self.myObjects.append(myObject); // crash!
    }
}
```

It crashes with the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type 'MyOtherObject' does not match RLMArray type 'MyObject'.'
```

Since `MyOtherObject` is a subclass of `MyObject` I cannot understand why the app is crashing at this point with this error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realm `List`s are not covarient. You can only store objects of exactly the declared type in them.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.myObjects = List<MyObject>();
```

This is not a proper value

```
self.myObjects = List<Needs actual object here not class>();
```

Comment: Yes Thomas answered already but thank you. My live would be so much easier if I could develop iOS Apps using Java.....